# Как передать id?

Tags: javascript

Здраствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне передать id (div-а) при клике на него (ниже пример)

```
<div class="Content" id="div3.1" onClick="Func_Id_Div"  >Папка 3.1</div>
```

И при выполнении этой функции надо, чтоб "Папка 3.1" залилась светло синим цветом (и параллельно все другие дивы, которые есть очистились от заливки. Ну, я так думаю, надо сначала все дивы от заливки почистить, а после на который кликнули залить. Но вот не могу прописать это.

Comment: onClick="Func_Id_Div(this.id)" передать id так, а про заливки не понятно без кода

Comment: Всем большо спасибо решение нашол (подтолкнули на хорошую мысль) и я забыл указать что нельзя пользоваться фраймворками (а jquery относится к ним к сожалению:))Ещё раз всем огромное спасибо!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <style>
        .content {
            width: 100%;
            background-color: lightgrey;
            height: 100px;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="content" id="div3.1">Палка 3.1</div>
    <div class="content" id="div3.2">Палка 3.2</div>
    <div class="content" id="div3.3">Палка 3.3</div>

    <script>

        $(".content").click(function() {
            alert(this.id);
            $(".content").css("background-color", "");
            $(this).css("background-color", "red");
        });
    </script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/54Awe/2/ я так понял, в конечном счёте такое нужно?

Answer (score 0):

Вам достаточно передать в функцию сам `div`( т.е самого себя ), на котором и произошло событие:

```
<div class="Content" id="div3.1" onClick="Func_Id_Div(this)" >Папка 3.1</div>

<script>
function Func_Id_Div(obj)
{
// Some actions with div-object....
}
</script>
```

Comment: А вот это уже интересно! За что минус? Обоснуйте.

---
Или это @karmadro4 опять влипил минус и убежал в свою нору?

Answer (score 0):

ппц, не кажется ли что jQuery слишком много для такой задачи?

function Func_Id_Div(obj)
{
return this.id;
}

Answer (score -3):

```
$('.Content').click(function(){
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
   $('.Content').css('background-color','white');
   $(this).css('background-color','blue');
});
```

Comment: Как-же меня бесит, что практически все по 100500 раз инициализируют `$(this)`, вы вообще понимаете что делает этот код?

И главный вопрос 

       var id = $(this).attr('id'); // wtf? какой смысл в этой строке?
       var id = this.id; // все, зачем тут инициализировать новый объект jquery?

Comment: @AlexWindHope, как всегда поддерживаю.